# Making a Celery task that depends on another, but both are retried if failed

Tags: python, celery

Celery version: 3.1.23

I currently have two Celery tasks that each run a function asynchronously and independent of one another. If either fails, they're retried a few times.

I want to run task A after task B, so that if task B is run it's guaranteed that A finished. However, I don't want to lose the retry functionality for either task.

What's the best way to do this using the Celery API?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `chain` can help you? I can't explain in better than official docs :)
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/canvas.html#chains